# How to store a value in javascript and use it in server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use store a dropdown selected value in a local variable inside javascript function once dropdown is changed and when I click an anchor tag to make the controller call, I could retrieve that value.

I am currently trying to use Jquery dropdown change function to store that dropdown value(but don't know how).

I can't use viewbag in javascript.
I tried hidden value but not sure if that is the right approach as I am not submitting the form.

Is there anyway to store and retrieve that variable value in server side?

Comment: You need make a ajax call, first I suggest learn about ajax

Comment: !ZachI updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **HTML**

```
<select id="DropDown" name="routetype">
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="second">Second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
</select>

<a id="anchor" href="#" />
```

### **JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selected;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        selected = $("#DropDown option:selected").attr('value');

        $('#DropDown').change(function () {  //Preserve the selected value here.
            selected = $("#DropDown option:selected").attr('value');
            return false;
        })
```

Send the selected dropdown value to Controller as mentioned by Ajaxifying below.

### **Ajax request on clicking the link**

```
        $('#anchor').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller Name")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Param: selected }),   //Dropdown value
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function () {                             //Success Callback
        });
    });
</script>
```

### **Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Param)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `POST` and `GET` requests.
Here is a [link](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html) detailing the difference.
You will probably want to use ajax to make these calls without a page refresh, in which case [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is handy.

Comment: I am currently using Jquery dropdown change function to store that dropdown value. But I have an anchor tag to call a controller function but How can I retrieve that value?